# jquery (javascript) refresh div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bear with me. I recently started implementing jquery at work. I created a new app already so I do have an understanding of what goes but I have not fully grasped it yet.

I have this function below that is being called everytime someone clicks a checkbox in a table wrapped in a unique div id. Currently, the table does not refresh until you close the dialog box. I want the div to refresh after the the server finishes its request.

I got it to work only for the first row in the table by simply calling the displayMid function again (that is commented out in the code below).

How do I get this to work for all the table rows? You can see I have been trying a few things already.  ;-)

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

```
function addRemoveMid(count, testpid) {
        var x = testpid;
        var y = $("#Mid" + count).text();
        var a = $("#midcheckbox" + count).is(':checked');
        //alert(x);
        if (!$("#midcheckbox" + count).is(':checked')) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "content_backend_pub_pid.ashx",
                data: { cmd: '10', pid: x, mid: y },
                type: "get",
                async: false,
                success: function(o) {
                    //displayMid(count);
                    //$("#inputDiv4").replaceWith($('#inputDiv4', $(html)));
                }
            });
            //$(this.addRemoveMid(count);
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                url: "content_backend_pub_pid.ashx",
                data: { cmd: '9', pid: x, mid: y },
                type: "get",
                async: false,
                success: function(o) {
                    //displayMid(count);
                    //$("#inputDiv4").replaceWith($('#inputDiv4', $(html)));
                }
            });
            //displayMid(count);
        }
        //$("#inputDiv4").fadeOut("fast").html('reload.php').fadeIn("fast");
    }
```

Comment: You should post the code in your app that calls the function "addRemoveMid", because it's not at all clear what's going on.

Comment: I left work for the weekend so I will not be able to give you the actual code until Monday, but I can try to summarize it. Its an html checkbox that has an Onclick=addRemoveMID(count). The count is there to keep track of what record I am modifying.

Does that help? If not, I will wait until I get back on Monday to post the call...

Comment: Here is that statement that calls the addRemoveMid function...
<code>
htmlString.Append("<td align=\"center\"><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"midcheckbox" + count.ToString() + "\" value=\"0\" onclick=\"addRemoveMid(" + count.ToString() + ",'"+ testpid +"');\"></input></td></tr>");
</code>

If you need more details, let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plans changed and my boss said he would rather have it refresh on close. So it is fine the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

'Currently, the table does not refresh until you close the dialog box' what this means? I see only a commented alert(x).What dialog box are you talking about?

Comment: Hi Octopus-Paul.  This type of response really belongs as a 'comment' underneath the question.  This section is for answers, and as such should stick to, well, answers :)

Comment: There is a dialog box that I create in a previous javascript function. See comment above. Hopefully that helps clarify. If not, I will post the actual code on Monday.